# git-tfs mapping git usernames to tfs domain names

Tags: git-tfs

I see on the git-tfs github page there is a way to map domain names to git names with the authors switch, however I'm looking to do the other way around, and up til now it does not seem to be working. I have a repository already pulled down, and I am trying to set up a new person working on our git repo (it was previously just me on the team), I've done some research and I can't seem to find an effective way of doing this.

I'm sure I am just being rather stupid and over looking something very simple.

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of an author file for mapping in this "direction" because the one that push the changeset is authenticated by the TFS workspace created under the hood to push the changes.

But, indeed, you'd better share the exactly same author file (which is cached in the '.git' folder) for 2 reasons :

- get exactly the same hash for each changeset fetched from TFS (and perhaps in the future share some commits between your local repositories)
- if you push commits written by another colleague, the committer will be done with the identity of your colleague (if you active the good option in tfs) thanks to the author file (the mapping is used in the other way) and not with the identity of the one who push the commit.